# How to re-format number to time in php?

Tags: php

I am creating a room booking system with some information like End-user needs to select in difference inputs

- Date booking
- Time booking (custom fixed value (08:00, 08:30,... ...17:30) store into database as number (800,830 ...n)
- End-user need to tell how many hours need to book.( 1hr, 1hr 30, 2hr ...8hr) per day/date (The hour here will calculate in minute like 1hre = 60min, 2hrs = 120min ...n)

Base on above information, I would like to dynamic calculate the end time of the meeting. Let said, end user select booking date= 2022-02-05, start-time = 08:30 and select duration = 1hr 30min. Of course the end time is 10:00 but how to calculate the end time?

Here is my html code

```
               <input type="date" class="form-control" id="bookingdate" name="bookingdate" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required>

               <select id="selecttime" name="selecttime" style="width: 130px !important;" class="rounded-right text-center bd-outline" required data-header="Select a dept" onfocus="document.getElementById('errtxt').innerText='';">
                    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Start time</option>
                    <option value="08:00">08:00</option>
                    <option value="08:00">08:30</option>
                    <option value="09:00">09:00</option>
                    <option value="09:30">09:30</option>

                    <option value="17:30">17:30</option>
                </select>

                <select id="duration" name="duration" style="width: 120px !important;"  class="rounded-right text-center bd-outline" required ">
                    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select</option>
                    <option class="text-start text-secondary" value="30">30 min</option>
                    <option  class="text-start" value="60">1 hr</option>
                    <option  class="text-start text-secondary" value="90">1hr 30min</option>
                    <option  class="text-start" value="120">2 hrs</option>

                    <option  class="text-start text-secondary" value="510">8hrs 30min</option>
                </select>
```

And here is my php code after post the html form

```
        $Booking_Date = $_POST["bookingdate"];//let said val = 2022-02-05
        $Booking_Time = $_POST["selecttime"];//val like 08:00, 08:30 ...
        $Duration = $_POST["duration"]; //val like 30min, 60min, 90min,....450min
```

As of this code I have no idea to capture end time of the meeting

I tried this but I think it will have something better because I will store each value separately into database and I think PHP will have other function/choice that I don't know ....

```
        $StartTime     = new DateTime($Booking_Date . $Booking_Time);
        $minutesToAdd = $Duration;

        echo "Start time " . $StartTime->format('Y-m-d H:i');

        $StartTime->modify("+{$minutesToAdd} minutes");

        echo "<br />End time " . $StartTime->format('H:i');
```

Could anyone suggest me other better idea?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why is sql-server in the tags ?

Comment: Actually, it's not mandatory for here but this project I connect to sql-server.

Comment: Yes, but now you have all people that follow the sql-server tag here on SO reading your question, while they are not interested in php or html questions. This is a waist of time for us

Comment: Yes, I removed it.

Comment: What's wrong with your code? You need to store, at least, start date and duration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) like so:

```
$Booking_Date = "2022-02-05";
$Booking_Time = "08:30";
$Duration = "30min";

$Duration_minutes = str_replace("min", "", $Duration); // Removes "min"
// Store this value in your database
$booking_datetime = $Booking_Date . " " . $Booking_Time; // Assumes 24h format
// Store this value in your database under DATETIME format

$meeting_end_timestamp = strtotime($booking_datetime) + $Duration_minutes * 60; // Adds duration in seconds
$meeting_end = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $meeting_end_timestamp); // Convert timestamp to formatted date

echo $meeting_end; // Outputs "2022-02-05 09:00:00"
```

If you want to change the output's format: see [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php).